# SharePoint 2013 - How to add additional page head?

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, page-layout

I am using the Oslo Masterpage, and it has an AdditionalPageHead control, which I'd like to use. I'm using the footer currently and I'd like to add the header but I don't know how. I added the following for the footer:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
<%--SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter"  AllowMultipleControls="false" /--%>
<div id="footer" class="noindex">
   <p style="text-align:center;">Some fancy footer is displayed here.</p>
</div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Can anyone guide me on what to add for the header to appear on my pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Since AdditionalPageHead is a Content Place Holder, you can use respective `asp:Content` control as shown below:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">
    <!-- Add stuff here -->
</asp:Content>
```

You can add more Content Place Holders anywhere in the MasterPage and use them in the Pages.

Comment: Arsalan can we use this multiple times (i.e. lf we build a conditional statement in the custom page layout?)

Comment: Try that if it works we can use it :)